# SOAP from Android giving 404

Tags: android, soap, http-status-code-404, android-ksoap2

So I'm getting **http error 404** indicating I'm trying to access something which isn't there. I can't seem to figure out whats missing or that I've misunderstood.

- Namespace: `http://tempuri.org/`
- URL: `http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc?wsdl`
- Action: `SetPulseOxi`
- Soap_action: `http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/SetPulseOxi`

The soap service works from `SOAPUI` but not from my `ksoap2` Android implementation. I've also tryed sending raw SOAP that I know worked through SOAPUI.

Example request from Android ksoap:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <SetPulseOxi xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <DeviceID>test1</DeviceID>
            <UnitID>test2</UnitID>
        </SetPulseOxi>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

This is the full wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="PulseOxiSvc" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IPulseOxi_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <http:BasicAuthentication xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http"/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfHomeCare"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IPulseOxi_GetPulseOxiById_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPulseOxiById"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IPulseOxi_GetPulseOxiById_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPulseOxiByIdResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IPulseOxi_GetAllPulseOxi_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAllPulseOxi"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IPulseOxi_GetAllPulseOxi_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAllPulseOxiResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IPulseOxi_SetPulseOxi_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetPulseOxi"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IPulseOxi_SetPulseOxi_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetPulseOxiResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IPulseOxi">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPulseOxiById">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/GetPulseOxiById" message="tns:IPulseOxi_GetPulseOxiById_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/GetPulseOxiByIdResponse" message="tns:IPulseOxi_GetPulseOxiById_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetAllPulseOxi">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/GetAllPulseOxi" message="tns:IPulseOxi_GetAllPulseOxi_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/GetAllPulseOxiResponse" message="tns:IPulseOxi_GetAllPulseOxi_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SetPulseOxi">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/SetPulseOxi" message="tns:IPulseOxi_SetPulseOxi_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/SetPulseOxiResponse" message="tns:IPulseOxi_SetPulseOxi_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="IPulseOxi" type="tns:IPulseOxi">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#IPulseOxi_policy"/>
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetPulseOxiById">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/GetPulseOxiById" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetAllPulseOxi">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/GetAllPulseOxi" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SetPulseOxi">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/SetPulseOxi" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="PulseOxiSvc">
        <wsdl:port name="IPulseOxi" binding="tns:IPulseOxi">
            <soap:address location="http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc/WcfHomeCare"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure if this is a help or breakthrough ... or just nothing

if you change the URL to `http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc/WcfHomeCare`
with target `http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/SetPulseOxi` i got a result (Android ksoap2)
result is: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

if i use action as `http://tempuri.org/SetPulseOxi` i got a 500 response
unfortunately i could not get a correct response, at least the URL thing is 100% a breakthrough.

here is the code i used:

```
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL = "http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc/WcfHomeCare";
    String methodName = "SetPulseOxi";
    String soapAction = "http://tempuri.org/IPulseOxi/SetPulseOxi";//NAMESPACE + methodName;
    
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);
    
    PropertyInfo hhh = new PropertyInfo();
    hhh.setName("DeviceID");
    hhh.setValue("testA");
    hhh.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(hhh);
    
    PropertyInfo ddd = new PropertyInfo();
    ddd.setName("UnitID");
    ddd.setValue("testB");
    ddd.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(ddd);
    
    PropertyInfo asas = new PropertyInfo();
    asas.setName("UserID");
    asas.setValue("1");
    asas.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(asas);
    
    PropertyInfo jkjk = new PropertyInfo();
    jkjk.setName("pulse_avg");
    jkjk.setValue("1");
    jkjk.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(jkjk);
    
    PropertyInfo location = new PropertyInfo();
    location.setName("pulse_max");
    location.setValue("1");
    location.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(location);
    
    PropertyInfo xx = new PropertyInfo();
    xx.setName("pulse_min");
    xx.setValue("1");
    xx.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(xx);
    
    PropertyInfo yy = new PropertyInfo();
    yy.setName("spO2_avg");
    yy.setValue("1");
    yy.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(yy);
    
    PropertyInfo as = new PropertyInfo();
    as.setName("spO2_max");
    as.setValue("1");
    as.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(as);
    
    PropertyInfo ff = new PropertyInfo();
    ff.setName("spO2_min");
    ff.setValue("1");
    ff.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(ff);
    
    PropertyInfo tt = new PropertyInfo();
    tt.setName("uid");
    tt.setValue("1");
    tt.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(tt);
    
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 15000);
    androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
        String result = envelope.getResponse().toString() ;
        Log.i("YAZAN", result);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

** plz ignore property stupid names :) **

**More Details:**
if you open
`http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc?wsdl`
go down to end of file, you will see this

```
<wsdl:service name="PulseOxiSvc">
<wsdl:port name="IPulseOxi" binding="tns:IPulseOxi">
<soap:address location="http://testnet.medisat.dk:81/WcfHomeCare/PulseOxiSvc.svc/WcfHomeCare"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

as you can see location="http://.../WcfHomeCare"
i worked with SOAP services before, but location was the same as URL
so i am not sure if this is something optional to set a different URL for location or it's based on specific needs.

from there, i think rest of story is yours :)

Comment: Marked with +1 as I can actually get input now, I'll just have to verify everything works as it should.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped out, can you explain how you found out? And for future records how I should've been able to tell that I had to add the extra to the path? I know the error indicated something like this was the problem, but how to figure out what the right path should be?

Comment: THANK YOU!, ok how i did that, i looked at SoapUI address after adding the service, so i saw a new URL, my curiosity pushed me to know how did soapUI figured out that URL, i thought it should be mentioned somewhere, first thought was at WSDL page, so i went there and found the same URL , i will edit the answer to append details

Comment: BTW, how have you guys, figure out the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" ?. I try to reproduce the solution but stuck at this part.

Comment: i am not sure about this, as i reported to @Warpzit about that, but i did not rework on the calls of that service, it's mainly a server-side error, so i think Warpzit can answer this

Comment: @ToYonos you should make a new question on stack but for my part I had to change the format of my xml.